# MySQL - complex query using left join to fetch unassigned resource

Tags: mysql, left-join

I have the following fiddle http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/5c089/2

Here's the schema for the DB tables:

**classes**:

```
id
school_id
```

**classes_academic_years**:

```
id
class_id
name
academic_year_id
grade
```

**classes_subjects**:

```
id
class_academic_year_id
subject_id
```

**class_masters**:

```
id
class_academic_year_id
professor_id
```

**professors**:

```
id
school_id
first_name
last_name
```

**professors_subjects**:

```
id
professor_id
subject_id
```

**professors_classes_subjects**:

```
id
professor_id
class_academic_year_id
subject_id
```

**subjects**:

```
id
name
school_id
default
```

I've got two queries:

```
select subjects.* from subjects
inner join professors_subjects on professors_subjects.subject_id = subjects.id
where professors_subjects.professor_id = 198;
```

and

```
SELECT DISTINCT `subjects`.* 
FROM `subjects` 
INNER JOIN `classes_subjects` ON classes_subjects.subject_id = subjects.id 
INNER JOIN `classes_academic_years` ON classes_academic_years.id = classes_subjects.class_academic_year_id 
LEFT JOIN `professors_classes_subjects` ON professors_classes_subjects.class_academic_year_id = classes_subjects.class_academic_year_id and professors_classes_subjects.subject_id = classes_subjects.subject_id 
left join `class_masters` on class_masters.class_academic_year_id = classes_academic_years.id
WHERE ((professors_classes_subjects.id is null or professors_classes_subjects.professor_id = 198) and class_masters.professor_id = 198 ) 
AND (classes_academic_years.academic_year_id = 3) 
AND (subjects.default = 0) 
ORDER BY `name` asc;
```

The first one simply fetches all of the subjects assigned to a certain professor (professor_id = 198).

The second one fetches all the subjects assigned to a certain professor (professor_id = 198) to the class that the professor is a class master of, as well as all of the subjects of that class that are unassigned to any other professor. (e.g. professor_id = 198 has assigned the subject_id = 67 for class_id = 426, but there are two more unassigned subjects from that class which have to be fetched).

In the given example, the first query fetches the subjects having IDs 76 and 67, and the second one fetches the subjects having IDs 86, 72 and 67.

Both of these queries work just fine. However, I need a third query which combines these two (e.g. it should fetch subjects having IDs 76, 67, 86 and 72). I would prefer using left joins, thus avoiding the UNION operator.

Do you have any thoughts for the third query?

Comment: Why would you prefer `LEFT JOIN` over `UNION`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this:

```sql
SELECT DISTINCT `subjects`.* 
FROM `subjects` 
INNER JOIN `classes_subjects` ON classes_subjects.subject_id = subjects.id 
INNER JOIN `classes_academic_years` ON classes_academic_years.id = classes_subjects.class_academic_year_id 
LEFT JOIN `professors_classes_subjects` ON professors_classes_subjects.class_academic_year_id = classes_subjects.class_academic_year_id and professors_classes_subjects.subject_id = classes_subjects.subject_id 
left join `class_masters` on class_masters.class_academic_year_id = classes_academic_years.id

left join professors_subjects on professors_subjects.subject_id = subjects.id

WHERE (((professors_classes_subjects.id is null or professors_classes_subjects.professor_id = 198) and class_masters.professor_id = 198 ) 
AND (classes_academic_years.academic_year_id = 3) 
AND (subjects.default = 0)) 

OR professors_subjects.professor_id = 198

ORDER BY `name` asc;
```

I introduced another left join (to join the table you have in the first query), and added OR logic to the whole WHERE clause.